# Selenium: embed chromeDriver and geckodriver into my exe

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can I make a selenium Project to one exe without installation?
I want to embed chromeDriver and geckodriver into my exe.

[image]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, you can do what you asked for this way:
First, add ChromeDriver.exe to your project as an embedded resource (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319292/how-to-embed-and-access-resources-by-using-visual-c for more details). This will embed ChromeDriver.exe directly into your compiled application.
Then when you're application starts, read the content of that resource (as a stream of bytes) and write that content to a new file. Name this file ChromeDriver.exe. This way your application "spawns" ChromeDriver.exe from within itself.
Finally, instantiate the ChromeDriver class, and pass the path to the newly created ChromeDriver.exe file.

However, while this solution looks cool, embedding ChromeDriver.exe by itself isn't enough. You also need to have all of your references, including Webdriver.dll in the same folder as your application. In fact, most.net applications can be installed just by copying a folder, but not just as a single file. Theoretically, you can also embed all of the dlls that your project needs and load then into memory when the applicator starts, but that's a huge overkill for most cases. Therefore, if deploying a folder instead of a single file is acceptable, then you can simply add ChromeDriver.exe to that output folder (by adding it to the project as a content file with the Copy Always setting), and save all the work of spawning it from the resource.

Lastly, one important note: if you embed ChromeDriver.exe as an embedded resource, you'll have harder time updating it when new version is published, than if you'd use the NuGet package that installes it as a separate file for you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the process is so easy by following several steps!

- According to Arnon Axelrod's answer, you should put your chromedriver file as an embedded resource file to your project and create it on your application load.

  You can do this from: Solution Explorer -> Properties -> (double click on) Resources.resx

  a new tab will pop! then you can add your exe file like this picture:
  [Adding exe file as a resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkesp.png)
- In the next step you should select the added file from "Solution Explorer" and make it as an embedded resource file from "Properties" window of the selected file. This picture may help you more: [Setting a resource file as an embedded resource file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5staZ.png)
- Then you can use the following functions to read, create and delete the driver file:

```c#
//Reading and creating the chrome driver file
void ExtractResource(string path)
{
    byte[] bytes = Properties.Resources.chromedriver;
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
}
```

```c#
//Create the chromedriver file on form load
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string exePath = ".\\ChromeDriver.exe";
    ExtractResource(exePath);
}
```

```c#
//Deleting the created file
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    File.Delete(exePath);
}
```

- Now you can refrence the ChromeDriver File when creating the ChromeDriver object using the following code:

```c#
ChromeDriver chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(@".\\");
```

It's also better to check if the file exists or not before creating the above object!

- For the last step you should embed your dll files in your exe output. The most straightforward way to achieve this is by installing "Fody" from NuGet package manager. you can check [this link](https://github.com/Fody/Home/blob/master/pages/usage.md) for more information about adding this awesome tool to your project.

Comment: Hello, this part does not work: byte[] bytes = Properties.Resources.chromedriver;